# How can I copy packages installed in one Ubuntu PC directly to another Ubuntu PC of similar version without downloading anything

Tags: package-management

I have two PCs and one of them is on Ubuntu 20, now I am going to install Ubuntu 20 on my other PC also. In the PC running Ubuntu, I have installed many packages which had consumed a lot of internet during installation. So I am looking for a way of transferring all the packages installed in one PC directly to the other. Is this possible?

Comment: Ubuntu 20?  so you're asking about *snap* packages as used by Ubuntu Core 20  (20.04 or a *year.month* system can use *deb*, *snap* and various other packages (flatpak etc); however the *year* format systems (ie. 20) systems however are *snap* only).   Have a look in `/var/lib/snapd/snaps/`

Comment: Ubuntu Core is a sub-optimal choice for a system with constrained or metered internet. But if you really want to, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266894 includes an example how to install a copied (instead of downloaded) snap package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On both systems the same package sources have to be active.
Configure apt on your 1. system to hold the downloaded packages in cache /var/cache/apt/archives. This is no longer standart.

```
cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01keep-debs 
# Heruntergeladene Pakete behalten.
Binary::apt::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
APT::Get::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
Binary::apt-get::APT::Keep-Downloaded-Packages "true";
```

Now you can copy the debs from 1. System to 2. one.

Your second system needs internet access too, for refreshing available packages. If apt (on 2. system)founds it in his cache it will take it.

Answer (score 0):

Packages that are downloaded following an `apt install` are cached in `/var/cache/apt/archives`, with the purpose of eventually reusing them without needing to download them again.

Thus, these downloaded `.deb` files could be copied to the same directory on the other machine. If an install command is issued on that machine, the locally stored copies of the archives will be used if they are still matching the versions on the software servers.